# Cytoscape How to select a specific GPU card? Nvidia over Intel

Tags: gpu, opencl, cytoscape

My pc has two cards: one Intel and one NVIDIA. Although I select the NVIDIA card in the Cytoscape Desktop OpenCl preferences everything runs in the Intel one.
How can I force it to use the NVIDIA one?
Many thanks!

I already made sure I have installed all the appropriate drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the [Cytoscape 3.10 Beta](https://cytoscape-builds.ucsd.edu/cytoscape-builds/Cytoscape-3.10.0/beta1/) and see if it works better?  Please keep in mind that this is a beta, so bugs are probably present...